# wsjt-x problems with windows 11 Icom 7300 USB sound hangs

Tags: icom, ft8, wsjt-x, icom-ic-7300, windows

Description of problem:

WSJT and JTDX both stop receiving sound after about 2-3 hours when running on Win 11 with ICom 7300.
This did not happen with my Raspberry Pi running the same rig.

The waterfall shows black about 2-3 hours after starting the program. The time is not reproducible. This happens with both WSJT and JTDX.

If I quit WSJT and restart, the waterfall shows it receiving sound data again. Same for JTDX.

I am using the Icom 7300 drivers and the USB CODEC is set as audio in/out on preferences.

System:

I have a windows 11 PC (Beelink Mini S12 Pro Mini PC).
Rig is Icom 7300.
Up to date Icom drivers.

Comment: Hi Peter, have you completely disabled power management, hibernation, etc. in Windows?

Comment: I already disabled all power sleep etc.
New info: It is related to logging out of Remote Desktop.
As long as I am logged into remote desktop, it works.
Seems this has been known for a while by Microsoft, not sure if there is a solution now:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-remote-desktop-session-sound-stops-when/40594f6f-933a-4a2e-90cc-388fd4410851?page=4